# "a company which name is" or "there is a company whose name is"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

"a company which name is..." or "there is a company whose name is..."?

which one is correct?

I know I need to use 'whose' when the preceding noun is living thing.
For example, there is a boy whose job is a teacher.

Comment: Is there a reason you must use this construction? It'd be much more common to say "a company with the name ...." or "a company named". This construction seems a bit wordy. Also, your second example would make more sense as "there is a boy whose job is teaching" or, even better, "there is a boy who is a teacher".

Comment: You can use **whose** with non-living thigs too.

Comment: One usual, but clunky, work-around is, "a company, the name of which is..." Hardly poetic, but correct, unlike, "a company which name is..."

Comment: Hmm... Maybe a company is a living thing? But I think it has more to do with anything you name, rather than whether it is living or not.

Comment: I assume the OP didn't mean that only living things use 'whose', but rather that living things use 'whose' and the question here is whether inanimates use 'whose' or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are correct:

- A company whose name is ...
- A company, of which the name is ...
- A company, the name of which is ...

...although in many cases the following might sound more natural:

- A company named ...
- A company called ...
- A company by the name of ...

The following are wrong:

- A company which name ...
- A company which the name ...

See also:

- http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/whose
- http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whose